# where to copy media files to test widevine on chromcast

Tags: casting, chromecast, widevine

I have to test playback of DASH Content on Cast device with custom receiver app.

Where should i copy my custom media files?

I have tested coping in drive and drop box but not playing.

Getting Error like Media Element State :"Stalled"
Media Player State :"underflow:true" 
first I am getting Media Host State: "Success"
After few minutes "Fatal Error:code =3"﻿

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a server that supports, among other things, CORS headers. For testing purposes, it can be a simple apache server, for example. In production, you need to have SSL certs signed by a valid authority.

Comment: Thanq for replay i have already tested with apache by adding " Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" " in config file for CORS. But same thing.

Comment: There is very little information from your side to be able to help you with the issues you are having. I suggest you narrow down the issue by first using a Styled or the Default receiver (or use the reference receiver from https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample) to see if those receivers can play your stream or not. You would need to show more receiver log if that fails.

Comment: I am using (CastMediaPlayerStreamingDRM) from github. Is there any codec specs for video to test playback

Comment: Please use the reference sample app that I had mentioned instead.

Comment: whe i was open that github.com/googlecast/Cast-Player-Sample i am getting blank screen not any receiver info

Comment: That sample app is a receiver not a sender, so did you configure your app to use that receiver?